90s movie about a callboy and a callgirl who meet at a bar and each thinks the other is a customer
I saw the movie about a decade ago in free TV. So most likely it's an 80s, a 90s or an early 2000s movie because it didn't look too old.
I only remember this scene, most likely at the beginning of the movie:
A man and a woman are in a (hotel?) bar, not knowing each other when they get in contact. One of them says something like "$50 for the night?" and the other one accepts. So they go to the (hotel?) room of one of them. Each of them thinks the other one will pay them the money. At the room, each of them wants the money beforehand when they notice their mistake that the other one is not a customer but also in the same business branch (competitor). After that, rivalry between them both begins.
The bar-scene and the their behavior in this scene is more gentleman/90s James Bond movie style. From my memory I would estimate their ages to be in their 30s/40s (so not a teenie comedy).
It was in color and I  saw it in German free TV but the style was to 99.99% not German but American/British, most likely Hollywood. Setting was most likely in a bigger American City like New York. If I remember correctly the time in the plot was about the same or a few years before the movie was produced.
The man was drinking a Scotch or Martini. Both of them were dressed higher class (with suite and evening dress). The bar itself was also more higher ups. Both of them had a white skin color.
While in the bar they used higher class language but in the room they got more colloquial.

Welcome to the community. You may have more helpful information than you realize. If you know, please also describe the language, plot locale, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

@John I added some info but since it has been a decade I am not fully sure about everything beeing exactly like this.

Highly unlikely it's this movie, but a similar scene happens in Deuce Bigalow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOqFPLLiR34

I believe you are referring tho the the movie The Escort (2015).
The scene I think you are referring to is about 9 mins into the movie.

Thank you for assisting the community. I certainly hope your suggestion proves to be exactly right. I invite you to look at other answered ID questions to get a feel how this community prefers to frame an ID answer. Here's an example. I hope you enjoy participating.

Since the OP saw the movie a decade ago, it probably isn't this movie.

Deuce Bigalow: Male Gigolo (IMDB). 
Rob Schneider becomes a male escort to pay for the repairs he caused by destroying an aquarium belonging to the real male escort. His first time he tries it, he runs into the girl-they come back to the house, she eventually recognizes the carpet and leaves. They argued about the price, had a matrix style fight. Not a great movie, but wasn't bad-somewhat funny.
